# Response.Redirect does not change url c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am building asp .net website using jQuery and jQueryMobile framework. after succesfull login i am able to see contents of next page but the URL remains the same i.e. `/Login.aspx`

When i press F5 then only URL changes.

Login.aspx

```
<div data-role="content">
    <form id="frmLogin" method="post" runat="server" action="Login.aspx">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="text" name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" placeholder="User Name" value="" runat="server" /><br />
            <input type="password" name="txtUserPass" id="txtUserPass" placeholder="Password" value="" runat="server" />
            <br />          
            <button id="cmdLogin" type="button">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="divDialog"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript called when clicked on `cmdLogin` Login button

```
$('#cmdLogin').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxExecute.aspx?Fn=VUSR',
        type: 'POST',
        context: document.body,
        data: 'User=' + $('#txtUserName').val() + '&Pass=' + $('#txtUserPass').val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(f);
            if (response == '1') {                    
                f.submit();
            }
            else {
                /*
                Print Error
                */
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Login Code Behind

Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {       
        routeToDefaultPage();
    }   
}
private void routeToDefaultPage()
{
    Response.Redirect("Piechart.aspx");
}
```

**What is problem here ?**

When i do inspect element after login successful (Contents of `Piecharts.aspx` but URL is `Login.aspx`) . i see following in head section

```
<base href="http://localhost:49712/Login.aspx">
```

Comment: try another browser, see if it changes there

Comment: Its a mobile website...i tried in Chrome & Android Browser..

Comment: it works well on opera mini web browser for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me...!!

```
$.mobile.changePage( "/Piecharts.aspx", {
  transition: "pop"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have flag ispostback assigned to true when you click. A break point on this line could help you?

Comment: Yes the breakpoint hits when you click on Login button... even the `function routeToDefaultPage()` gets called. thats why i am able to see contents of `Piecharts.aspx` page

Comment: Sorry i haven t understand the problem you are redirected to the right page but URL doesn't change. Have you try redirect to absolute path using Response.Redirect("/Piecharts.aspx"); You can also try before redirect to clear cache Response.Clear(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Response.Redirect("Piechart.aspx");
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about jquery redirect after ajax call?

Try to add this after ajax call success. `header( 'Location: Piechart.aspx' );` ?

```
$('#cmdLogin').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxExecute.aspx?Fn=VUSR',
        type: 'POST',
        context: document.body,
        data: 'User=' + $('#txtUserName').val() + '&Pass=' + $('#txtUserPass').val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            // redirects page after login successful
            header( 'Location: Piechart.aspx' );            

            alert(f);
            if (response == '1') {                    
                f.submit();
            }
            else {
                /*
                Print Error
                */
            }
        }
    });
});
```